# file output error relating to list dictionary and value

Tags: python, file, printing

So my code works fine but it won't only print out half of the correct result.
I am trying to write a header to a file. I have checked and print out the calculation, which is correct. However, I only got one file print out correctly with the correct number and didn't get the another file to print out.

```
lookup[uniprotID] =['177','26','418']
```

the file that didn't print out correctly has this information : `start 174 and end 196`.

That file should has this as a result:

> uniprotID | at 3 position
>
> YSADACERD

Here is my code.

```
for i, (start, end) in enumerate(searchPFAM(fname)):

    print start, end
    for item in lookup[uniprotID]:
        item, start, end = map(int, (item, start, end))

        if start <=end:
            if item in xrange(start, end+1):
                print item
                with open('newfile-%s.txt' % i,'w') as fileinput:
                    atPosition = (item)-start
                    result = str(atPosition)
                    fileinput.write(">"+uniprotID+' | at '+result +' position\n')
                    text=''.join(makeList[(start-1):(end)])
                    fileinput.write(text)
            else:
                with open('newfile-%s.txt' % i,'w') as fileinput:
                    fileinput.write(">"+uniprotID+' | '+ 'N/A\n')

                    text=''.join(makeList[(start-1):(end)])
                    fileinput.write(text)
```

Comment: `if item in xrange(start,end+1):` should be coded `if start <= item <= end:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MRAB said, there is a strong possibility you are overwriting the same file several times. Pull your `with` block outside of the `for item in lookup[...]` block to ensure the file is not overwritten. Note that if multiple items in `lookup[unitProtID]` match the if conditions, the file will be written to multiple times.

```
for index, (start, end) in enumerate(searchPFAM(fname)):
    with open('newfile-%s.txt' % index,'w') as fileinput:
        print start, end
        for item in lookup[uniprotID]:
            item, start, end = map(int, (item, start, end)) #You shouldn't be doing this here, you should convert these variables to ints when you first store them in "lookup".
            if start <= item <= end:
                print item
                result = str(item - start)
                fileinput.write(">{0} | at {1} position\n".format(uniprotID, result))
                fileinput.write(''.join(makeList[start-1:end]))
                break #exit loop, move onto next file.
        else:
                fileinput.write(">{0} | N/A\n".format(uniprotID))
                fileinput.write(''.join(makeList[start-1:end]))
```

If this is still giving you problems, I suggest you replace every instance of `fileinput.write(...)` with `print ...`, and see what your output says.

Comment: now i have a problem with overwriting it several time. Is there a way that i can see if any of the list in lookup[] match before i write

Comment: You have a `print item` statement in your code. Everytime that item prints, that's a match from `lookup`.

Comment: @ChadD: See my edit. After the first match, the code will stop writing to the same file.

Comment: @Joel Cornett: You renamed `i` to `index` in the header line of the `for` loop, but not in the `open`.

Comment: @JoelCornett break doesn't quite help because the number that in the range of start and end can be the last number of the makelist. This will still duplicate the header.

Comment: @ChadD: Yeah I was wondering about that (I wasn't quite sure if that was something you wanted or not) anyway, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem is that `open('newfile-%s.txt' % i,'w')` opens a file for writing, overwriting any existing file of that name. If that's the problem, try opening it for appending `open('newfile-%s.txt' % i,'a')`.

Comment: you are right about <code>a</code> but is there a way to stop it from re-writing a file after it find the it found the value/ calculate